# Calculating order form total

Tags: jquery, html

I've created an order form and trying to get it working so that it will calculate the total cost. I've got it working for when a cake type has been selected but it breaks when I try to add the value from the radio buttons. The radio buttons are for the user deciding if they want a photo on their cake or not.

This the html:

```
<label>Cake Type
<div class="select-style">
<select id="cake_type" class="cake_type" name="cake_type" required>
<option value="0" selected="selected">Select One</option>
<option value="5" >Round Golf Course</option>
<option value="10" >Oblong Football Pitch</option>
<option value="15" >Round Chocolate Sweetie</option>
<option value="20" >Round White Chocolate Sweetie</option>
<option value="25" >Round Unicorn Cake</option>
<option value="30" >Round Drip Cake</option>
<option value="35" >Football Cake</option>
<option value="40"> Yum Yum Cake</option>
<option value="45" >Oblong Carrot Cake</option>
<option value="50" >Round AFC Cake</option>
<option value="55" >Square 8" Cake</option>
<option value="60" >Oblong Cake</option>
</select>
</label> 
</div>

<p>Would you like a photo on your cake?(£7)</p>
<div>
<label class="checkbox-inline"></label>
    <input type="radio" name="photo[]" id="photo[]" value="7">Yes
</label>
<label class="checkbox-inline">
<input type="radio" name="photo[]" id="photo[]" value="0"/>No
</div>

 <input type="text" name="total"  id="totalPrice" value="£0" readonly="readonly" size="8">
```

This is the jQuery I have at the moment:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('change', '.cake_type', '.photo', function() {
        var cakeType, finalTotal;
        cakeType = $(' #cake_type option:selected ').val();
        photo = $('#photo option:checked').val(); 
        finalTotal = parseFloat(cakeType) + parseFloat(photo); 
        $(' #totalPrice ').val('£' + finalTotal.toFixed(2));
    });
});

</script>
```

At the moment when yes or no is selected nothing happens to the price but when an option for cake type is picked NaN appears. If I just have:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('change', '.cake_type', function() {
        var cakeType, finalTotal;
        cakeType = $(' #cake_type option:selected ').val(); 
        finalTotal = parseFloat(cakeType); 
        $(' #totalPrice ').val('£' + finalTotal.toFixed(2));
    });
});

</script>
```

it will work fine so it must be to do with this line:

```
photo = $('#photo option:checked').val();
```

but I can't figure out what it is, any help would be appreciated

Comment: Remove the `[]` from your input names and ids. Never use an id on more than 1 element, they are supposed to be unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason of NaN was when radio buttons are not checked the value is not int and the sum you will be NAN .

Check my changes:

https://jsfiddle.net/1kpu5qft/2/

```
// find elements
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('change', '.cake_type,.photo', function() {
        var cakeType, finalTotal;
        cakeType = $(' #cake_type option:selected ').val();

        photo = $('input[name="photo[]"]:checked').val(); 
        if(!photo)
            photo = 0;
        finalTotal = parseFloat(cakeType) + parseFloat(photo); 
        $(' #totalPrice ').val('£' + finalTotal.toFixed(2));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

give this a try:

```
<label>Cake Type
<div class="select-style">
<select id="cake_type" class="cake_type forminput" name="cake_type" required>
<option value="0" selected="selected">Select One</option>
<option value="5" >Round Golf Course</option>
<option value="10" >Oblong Football Pitch</option>
<option value="15" >Round Chocolate Sweetie</option>
<option value="20" >Round White Chocolate Sweetie</option>
<option value="25" >Round Unicorn Cake</option>
<option value="30" >Round Drip Cake</option>
<option value="35" >Football Cake</option>
<option value="40"> Yum Yum Cake</option>
<option value="45" >Oblong Carrot Cake</option>
<option value="50" >Round AFC Cake</option>
<option value="55" >Square 8" Cake</option>
<option value="60" >Oblong Cake</option>
</select>
</label>
</div>

<p>Would you like a photo on your cake?(£7)</p>
<div>
<label class="checkbox-inline"></label>
    <input type="radio" name="photo" id="photo" class="forminput" value="7">Yes
</label>
<label class="checkbox-inline">
<input type="radio" name="photo" id="photo" class="forminput" value="0" selected/>No
</div>

 <input type="text" name="total"  id="totalPrice" value="£0" readonly="readonly" size="8">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('change', '.forminput', function() {
        var cakeType, finalTotal;
        cakeType = $(' #cake_type option:selected ').val();
        photo = $('#photo:checked').val();
        finalTotal = parseFloat(cakeType) + parseFloat(photo);
        $(' #totalPrice ').val('£' + finalTotal.toFixed(2));
    });
});
 </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

First change your html inputs to this:

```
<label class="checkbox-inline">
    <input type="radio" name="photo" checked  class='photo' value="7">Yes
</label>
<label class="checkbox-inline">
<input type="radio" name="photo" class='photo' value="0"/>No
  </label>
```

And your script :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('change', '.cake_type,.photo', function() {
        var cakeType, finalTotal, photo;
        cakeType = $('.cake_type').val();
        photo = $('.photo:checked').val(); 
        finalTotal = parseFloat(cakeType) + parseFloat(photo); 
        $(' #totalPrice ').val('£' + finalTotal.toFixed(2));
    });
    });
```

You used "#photo" but there was no such id and there should not be same id on one page. 
About NaN, there was no radio checked by default so the code:

```
$('.photo:checked').val(); // returns NaN
```

Give this a try and let me know if I can help.

Comment: Thank you! That's working exactly how I needed it to now